# MDX: how to eliminate Column wise null values

Tags: ssas, mdx

How to eliminate Column wise null values in MDX?

[image]

```sql
WITH MEMBER [ReportName] AS [DimReport].[Report Key].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     MEMBER [ReportKey] AS [DimReport].[Report Key].CurrentMember.UniqueName
     MEMBER [ReportWiseLatestDate] AS TAIL(NonEmpty([DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].[Date Key],[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]),1).Item(0).MemberValue 
SELECT 
    {[ReportName],[ReportKey],[ReportWiseLatestDate]} ON COLUMNS,
    {[DimReport].[Report Key].[Report Key]} ON ROWS
FROM 
    [PopulationReportCube]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [NonEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/nonempty-mdx) function does the trick:

```
WITH MEMBER [ReportName] AS [DimReport].[Report Key].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     MEMBER [ReportKey] AS [DimReport].[Report Key].CurrentMember.UniqueName
     MEMBER [ReportWiseLatestDate] AS TAIL(NonEmpty([DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].[Date Key],[Measures].[DrPatientKeyCnt]),1).Item(0).MemberValue 
SELECT 
{[ReportName],[ReportKey],[ReportWiseLatestDate]} ON COLUMNS,
NonEmpty({[DimReport].[Report Key].[Report Key]}, [ReportWiseLatestDate]) ON ROWS
FROM 
[PopulationReportCube]
```

Comment: (upped) spot on answer